# For loop doesn't iterate over the whole list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with the for loop... This is what i mean in the title when the for loop doesn't iterate over the whole list:

```
for i in list:
    print(list)
```

output: `object 1, object 2...`

```
for i in list:
   print(list)
   list.delete()
```

output:`object1`

What do I do to have the loop iterate over the whole list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes when you delete the list before the loop finishes running. Doing:

```
for i in list:
    print(list)
    list.delete()
```

this deletes the list after executing once So if you want to loop through all items then delete the list do:

```
for i in list:
    print(list)
list.delete()
```

that deleted the list after it has finished running

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use

```
for _ in list:
    print(list)
list.delete()
```

In this code, we use the ' _ ' as a way to indicate that the variable isn't being used within the loop. It's a better way to use if you won’t plan to use the variable.

However if you want to iterate over the entire list and delete elements as you go, you could use:

```
for i in list:
    print(list)
list.delete(I)
```

or

If you want to delete elements from the list, I would iterate over a copy of the list instead. Here's an example:

```
for i in list.copy():
    print(i)
    list.remove(i)
```